# Remove suffix from certain column names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a_x':[1, 2, 3], 'b_x':[20, 30, 40], 'c_x':[10, 40, 50]})
```

How can I remove the suffix of first and third column names?

I don't want this approach:
`df = df.rename(columns={'a_x':'a', 'c_x':'c'})` that hardcoded them one by one.

**EDIT 1**: I have the list of the columns that I want to remove the suffix from. In this case I have `['a', 'c']`

My desired outcome looks like this:

```
    a    b_x   c
0    1   20   10
1    2   30   40
2    3   40   50
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your cols, and rename:

```
>>> target_cols = ['c']
>>> suffix = '_x'
>>> df.rename(columns={col + suffix: col for col in target_cols})

   a_x  b_x   c
0    1   20  10
1    2   30  40
2    3   40  50

# or
# df.rename(columns=dict(zip((col + suffix for col in target_cols), target_cols)))
```

Comment: Why not? Rename is fine if you know the suffix for each column and you construct the mapping with a loop.

Answer (score 6):

I think a simple `if/else` and a list comprehension will do here.

```
import pandas as pd 

trg_cols = ['a_x','c_x']
new_cols = [col.split('_')[0] if col in trg_cols else col  for col in df.columns]
```

---

```
df.columns = new_cols 
print(df)
   a  b_x   c
0  1   20  10
1  2   30  40
2  3   40  50
```

---

or if you want to select by your output target columns.

```
trg_cols = ['a','c']
new_cols = [col if not col.split('_')[0] in trg_cols else col.split('_')[0] 
            for col in df.columns]


df.columns = new_cols
print(df)
   a  b_x   c
0  1   20  10
1  2   30  40
2  3   40  50
```

---

of using`fillna` and `pd.Series`

```
trg_cols = ['a','c']
s = pd.Series(df.columns)
df.columns = s.str.extract('('+'|'.join(trg_cols)+')',expand=False).fillna(s)


print(df)
   a  b_x   c
0  1   20  10
1  2   30  40
2  3   40  50
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for python3.8 with the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions); since you already have a list of the columns:

```
df.rename(columns = lambda x: val if (val:=x.split("_")[0]) in ["a", "c"] else x)

   a  b_x   c
0  1   20  10
1  2   30  40
2  3   40  50
```